# How to present a date that can be parsed by any DateTimeFormatter pattern in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I'm working with a software that uses a lot of DateTimeFormat parsing, in order to minimize the errors, I wonder if I can present the date String in a certain way that it can be parsed by any DateTimeFormat pattern. Ideally it should work as follows:

```
String date = "...."
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(any pattern I want);
DateTime result = format.parseDateTime(date);
```

Or does the date have to follow the pattern? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not get one size fits all. Think if your string is not a legal date at all, something like "hello", how are you going to parse it?

## java.time

Java 8 and later includes the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework ([Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). The java.time [formatter’s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) pattern may contain `[]`to mark optional parts. This gives you some flexibility. Say you use format:

```
M[M]['/']['-']['.']d[d]['/']['-']['.']yyyy[' ']['T'][' ']h[h]:mm:ss
```

So in this case your string may have one or two digits specifying month, day and hour. Month, day and year may be separated by `.`, `-` or `/` and so forth. For example with format above the following strings will be parsed successfully:

```
1/10/1995 9:34:45
01-10-1995 09:34:45
01.10.1995T09:34:45
```

…and so forth.

I wrote a utility that has a set of patterns. Once it gets a String it tries to parse it with all the patterns in the set and sees if it succeeds with one of them. If you write such a set of patterns correctly you may ensure that your util supports any possible String that denotes a valid date.

Comment: Good answer. As stated, there is no ultimate pattern for every possible input. For example, `1/2/3`, which part is the abbreviated year, the month, and the day?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFromat let you set your own date patters. for example dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd etc..
This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can give you a better understanding about date patterns and how to use it

Comment: I know how to use date patterns but what I need is a date string that's like "one size fits all", aka it can be parsed by any date patterns, hopefully that make sense

Answer (score -1):

use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d=sdf.parse("07/12/2014");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The poster is looking for a generic pattern (which most likely does not exist), what you are suggesting is one very specific pattern.