# Test whether date-time field present in string pattern (java 8)

Tags: java, date, datetime

**Given:**

Valid, arbitrary date-time string pattern `strPattern`

Examples: `yyyyMMddHHmm`, `yyyyMMddHH` and so on

**Parsing `strPattern`**

`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( strPattern );`

**Question**

How do I test whether the `strPattern` contains seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc.?

My goal is to find out the "least" chronological unit the user has specified in their pattern (e.g. for `yyyyMMddHH` the "least" unit is hours).

**EDIT**

Is there something like `format.areHoursSpecified()` or `format.areDaysSpecified()` which test whether given `strPattern` contains special symbols denoting days, hours, etc.

A possible way is something like `strPattern.contains("H")` but this seems to be not a generic solution.

Comment: can you show us your code for this? the ones you have tried please

Comment: So you're actually looking for the PATTERN, i.e. the strings "yyyyMMdd...", or are you looking for numbers which follow the pattern? Otherwise strPattern.contains("H") is not a solution

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama The only code I have is `strPattern.contains("H")` since there are no methods in `DateTimeFormatter` like `areDaysSpecified()`

Comment: @dahui Yes, I am looking for string patterns, not numbers. However, I thought that since `DateTimeFormatter` parses arbitrary patterns it may "know" which set of chronological fields/units were specified in the pattern.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without seeing example input. Will there be ANY possible strings/characters around the date pattern? The job would be a lot easier if the string had delimeters around the value (e.g. "-yyyyMMdd-"), otherwise you might need a complex regular expression to match any combination of the y,M,d characters but not the surrounding characters

Comment: Check the use of this class. It might help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#getResolverFields--

Comment: @dahui The string pattern may contain any valid pattern for `DateTimeFormatter` like `M[M]['/']['-']['.']d[d]['/']['-']['.']yyyy[' ']['T'][' ']h[h]:mm:ss` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431845/how-to-present-a-date-that-can-be-parsed-by-any-datetimeformatter-pattern-in-jav). I know I can use regular expression but I seek for a standard solution

Comment: @Tom I saw that docs, they state "By default, a formatter has no resolver fields, and thus returns null."